# Is it possible to implement a high-side current mirror with only NMOS FETs?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, nmos

I need to implement a difference amplifier only using NMOS technology. I am struggling when trying to reference the voltage difference to ground. From my reading it looks like I need a high-side current mirror.

However, all of these are implemented using PMOS. Is there any way I can implement a high-side current mirror using NMOS?

Comment: Is there a reason for the NMOS constraint?

Comment: Look at the designs that where used before CMOS was invented. Then an NMOS diffpair would simply use a resistive load instead of a PMOS mirror. It would be a bit "silly" to try and design an NMOS only circuit unless there are special reasons and/or it is an exercise.